# Error in loads of programs

Tags: lubuntu, fonts, cairo

I've been getting a recurring error after using Lubuntu and trying to install a font.

```
python: /build/buildd/cairo-1.12.16/src/cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
```

This is the gist of it. Not a clue what I did wrong. But I can't use Lubuntu anymore and had to go back to Ubuntu 13.10.

Any ideas?

I tried clearing font cache and lot.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the font which seems to cause the error?

Answer (score 1):

This bug is still present in 14.04. There is a workaround.  In Preferences->Customize Look and Feel, under Widgets, change from "Lubuntu-default" to anything else.  I use "Mist".